# How can I make a minimum moves algorithm more efficient?

Tags: java, algorithm, breadth-first-search

There are 6 different tile colors that are arranged on a 2D rectangular grid. What is the minimum number of adjacent swaps (horizontal and vertical, not diagonal) that will result in no same colored tiles being adjacent? **The program must support grid sizes up to 15 x 15 and must return "no solution" if none exists**

My solution appears to work, but for no more than 16 - 20 tiles in the file. Otherwise it runs out of memory and/or takes too long.

My program looks for every tile that has another same colored one adjacent to it, and attempts to swap in all four directions (up, down, left, right). Those newly swapped grids are sent to a queue, which the program iterates through (as per the breadth-first-search method) and then applies the four way swap to each. The number of moves simultaneously are being tracked in another array. ArrayLists representing the grid are one dimensional and use integer values rather than Strings (to conserve memory) and the program uses math to determine adjacencies. It also tracks any before seen grids to terminate some unnecessary processing. This program does not account for a possibility of no solution occurring.

Below is the four way swap method (repeatedly called with iteration):

```
public static boolean minSwaps(ArrayList<Integer> tiles, int moves) {
    boolean solved = true;
    for (int i = 0; i < tiles.size(); i++) {
      if (hasAdjacent(tiles, i)) {
        solved = false;
        try {
          ArrayList<Integer> tilesNew = (ArrayList<Integer>)tiles.clone();
          Collections.swap(tilesNew, i, i - length);
          queue.add(tilesNew);
          Main.moves.add(moves + 1);
        }
        catch(Exception e) {}
        try {
          ArrayList<Integer> tilesNew = (ArrayList<Integer>)tiles.clone();
          Collections.swap(tilesNew, i, i + length);
          queue.add(tilesNew);
          Main.moves.add(moves + 1);
        }
        catch(Exception e) {}
        try {
          if (i + 1 % length != 0) {
            ArrayList<Integer> tilesNew = (ArrayList<Integer>)tiles.clone();
            Collections.swap(tilesNew, i, i + 1);
            queue.add(tilesNew);
            Main.moves.add(moves + 1);
          }
        }
        catch(Exception e) {}
        try {
          if (i % length != 0) {
            ArrayList<Integer> tilesNew = (ArrayList<Integer>)tiles.clone();
            Collections.swap(tilesNew, i, i - 1);
            queue.add(tilesNew);
            Main.moves.add(moves + 1);
          }
        }
        catch(Exception e) {}
      }
    }
    return solved;
  }
```

Additionally, here is a link to the program in its entirety with the file (replit.com)
https://replit.com/join/quivtthrqo-roya3

Comment: Can you add the code that defines some input, then calls the function, making it run for too long?

Comment: I am confused... do you want the code that initializes the files?

Comment: The code that we can run and see that indeed it takes too long. You've only provided a swap function. That is hardly enough for us to reproduce your performance problem.

Comment: I see, I will add it

Comment: Please don't link to a third-party for your complete code + example. Take the time to create a minimum reproducible example and post it in as simple a format (i.e. text) in your question. The easier you make it for others to understand and run your code the more likely you are to receive a high-quality answer. Please see https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example